# class cast exception: android.widget.textview

Tags: android

I want one help. I think this is a stupid question. But i done know the answer. 
my xml code is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bule_top" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Popuphead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Expense"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/closed" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Transaction Date "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Previous Balance "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Amount "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Current Balance "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In this xml only errer friends. Stack trace is.

```
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at com.elintsys.pocket.account.DailyReportActivity$9.onItemClick(DailyReportActivity.java:355)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-12 19:27:14.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But if I rearrange the xml like the following

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bule_top" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Popuphead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Expense"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Transaction Date "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Previous Balance "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Amount "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Current Balance "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" : "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/closed" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It works nice friends. I just rearrange the position of button. I want that button at top of the layout only. But it is didn't work. I don't know what is the reason friends. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to set height as wrap_content in place of 25dp

Comment: i think  it's error com.elintsys.pocket.account.DailyReportActivity java file please post the code

Comment: problem in DailyReportActivity on line 355

at com.elintsys.pocket.account.DailyReportActivity$9.onItemClick(DailyReportActivity.java:355)

Comment: Either your code is actually doing an illegal cast or the project needs to be cleaned (rearranging layouts sometimes causes ClassCastExceptions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes when you edit the XML files eclipse doesn't recompile correctly. Try cleaning your project with `Project` -> `Clean...` in the file menu.